# Should I connect to master node in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

The [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#clustering-and-clients) say:

> Assuming all cluster members are available, a client can connect to
>   any node and perform any operation. Nodes will route operations to the
>   queue master node transparently to clients.

What does this "route" mean exactly? Does the node I connected to redirect all the traffic to another node? It means that network utilization is doubled, doesn't it?

Should I try to connect to the master node of the queue when I'm only going to make operation on this single queue only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is, can I save some resources by connecting to the home
> node?

Yes you can, but it is a premature optimization that is probably not worth the effort. You can only verify this via running benchmarks.

You will probably spend more time developing code to ensure your application connects to the master node, setting up your benchmark environment and running them than you would save by this optimization.